# How to get the ssl session when using the sun HttpsServer

Tags: java, ssl, https, sun, com.sun.net.httpserver

I am using the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer` as Https Server and want to access the SSL session.

I handle the requests in a `HttpHandler`. When using a plain `SSLServerSocket` i can access the client certificate etc. via the `SSLSocket.getSession(...)` method but i couldn't found such a thing in the `HttpExchange` parameter of the `handle` method inside the `HttpHandler`.

Is there a way to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the `HttpExchange` to an `HttpsExchange` and get the `SSLSession` from that.